# Rmarkdown Beamer presentation, option clash clash for xcolor

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, beamer

I am trying to build a beamer presentation using rmarkdown. In my presentation I want to include tables using the `kable`, and `kableExtra` packages. I am having issues with this because one of the LaTex packages that `kableExtra` requires is already loaded by the beamer presentation with different options. This is the error message that I receive.

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.
```

I have been searching for a fix for this but have not had any luck. I have found solutions on the LaTex pages, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83101/option-clash-for-package-xcolor) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74805/latex-error-option-clash-for-package-xcolor), but I do not know LaTex and I have not figured out how to apply these solutions in the rmarkdown arena. I have tried looking at the Latex templates in rmarkdown, but I do not understand it well enough to try and implement these solutions.

Any thoughts or solutions would be much appreciated. Here is just a quick sample of the .Rmd that gives the error.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Author"
date: "April 28, 2018"
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
- \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]
```


## Slide with R Output

```{r cars, echo = TRUE}
kable(dt, format = "latex") 
```

## Slide with Plot

```{r pressure}
plot(pressure)
```
````

Comment: Adding `classoption: table` to your YAML header (at the top-level, so just after the `date:` line) should apply the suggestion in the first linked answer.

Comment: AH HA! nice! That absolutely worked. I was having trouble with it because I read those answers a couple days ago and forgot that you have to delete the option in the YAML. In fact, you omit loading the package in the header completely. Thank you. Still new to SO, so not sure if it matters, but if you change this to the answer I'll vote it.

Comment: Sure. Don't look to me for SO ettiquette tips though, I shouldn't really be posting answers in comments, I just don't like posting answers if I haven't tested them myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The linked answer on the TeX stackexchange suggests adding `table` to the class options for the document e.g. `\documentclass[a4paper,table]{article}`. In order to do this in RMarkdown, you can use a `classoption:` line in your YAML header:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Author"
date: "April 28, 2018"
classoption: table
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    keep_tex: true
---
```

Comment: `classoption: xcolor=table` would be even better to avoid problems with other packages which might use the same keyword

Comment: `classoption: xcolor=table` didn't work for me; what's the exact syntax?