# LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor in Rmarkdown for pdfOutput

Tags: r, r-markdown

Hopefully, this isn't a duplicate post. I took a look at some of the relevant questions that already exist and either it has to do with latex rather than r-markdown or it has to do with the "beamer" type output.

My program uses the package knitr. If I try to format my kable tables in latex format, I get the error message "! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor". Is there a workaround for r-markdown? What's specifically causing the clash?

Comment: Can you give us a code example? This will help us to reconstruct your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rmarkdown Beamer presentation, option clash clash for xcolor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50094698/rmarkdown-beamer-presentation-option-clash-clash-for-xcolor)